# Manually install xserver on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I tried to update my PI with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. However I get errors...

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Depends: xserver-common (>= 2:1.12.4-6+deb7u2) but 2:1.12.4-6 is installed
                     Recommends: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.10.2-4) but it is not installed
```

I tried running `apt-get -f install` but I get more errors...

```
Preparing to replace xserver-common 2:1.12.4-6 (using .../xserver-common_2%3a1.12.4-6+deb7u2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement xserver-common ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.12.4-6+deb7u2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/var/lib/xkb', which is also in package x11-xkb-utils 7.7~1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.12.4-6+deb7u2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

According to this: http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/updating.md maybe I need to update xserver manually. This is getting a bit out of my depth. Can anyone help? (if you know of a link that explains what to do that would be fine).

Answer (score 2):

Try to install `aptitude` which solves those problems more often